# Adding image backgroud to gtk 3 window hiding widgets and layouts

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtk2

I have created the GTK 3 window with multiple layouts, each contain some widgets on top of the main layout. Now I tried to add image background to the window. But the image is hiding all other layouts and widgets that exist in the main layout.

I have tested the same code in GTK 2, It is working as expected. (i.e) child layouts and widgets are showing on top of the pixmap.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
GtkWidget*
create_wndmain (void)
{
  GtkWidget *wndmain;
  GtkWidget *lytmain;
  GtkWidget *lytpreview;
  GtkWidget *txtpreview;
  GtkWidget *lytutils;
  GtkWidget *txtutils;
  GtkWidget *lytfsys;
  GtkWidget *txtfsys;
  GtkWidget *pixmap;

  wndmain = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (wndmain), _("Window"));
  gtk_window_set_position (GTK_WINDOW (wndmain), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (wndmain), 1024, 720);

  lytmain = gtk_layout_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_widget_show (lytmain);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (wndmain), lytmain);

  pixmap = gtk_image_new_from_file("pixmaps/layout-1920x1080.png");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (lytmain), pixmap);
  gtk_widget_show (pixmap);

  lytpreview = gtk_layout_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_widget_show (lytpreview);
  gtk_layout_put (GTK_LAYOUT (lytmain), lytpreview, 848, 88);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (lytpreview, 168, 480);
  gtk_layout_set_size (GTK_LAYOUT (lytpreview), 400, 400);

  pixmap = gtk_image_new_from_file("pixmaps/layout-1920x1080.png");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (lytpreview), pixmap);
  gtk_widget_show (pixmap);

  txtpreview = gtk_text_view_new ();
  gtk_widget_show (txtpreview);
  gtk_layout_put (GTK_LAYOUT (lytpreview), txtpreview, 8, 376);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (txtpreview, 144, 80);
  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (txtpreview)), _("\n\n        Preview Area"), -1);

  lytutils = gtk_layout_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_widget_show (lytutils);
  gtk_layout_put (GTK_LAYOUT (lytmain), lytutils, 664, 8);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (lytutils, 344, 72);
  gtk_layout_set_size (GTK_LAYOUT (lytutils), 400, 400);

  txtutils = gtk_text_view_new ();
  gtk_widget_show (txtutils);
  gtk_layout_put (GTK_LAYOUT (lytutils), txtutils, 16, 8);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (txtutils, 312, 56);
  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (txtutils)), _("\n \tUtility Area"), -1);

  lytfsys = gtk_layout_new (NULL, NULL);
  gtk_widget_show (lytfsys);
  gtk_layout_put (GTK_LAYOUT (lytmain), lytfsys, 8, 88);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (lytfsys, 192, 480);
  gtk_layout_set_size (GTK_LAYOUT (lytfsys), 400, 400);

  txtfsys = gtk_text_view_new ();
  gtk_widget_show (txtfsys);
  gtk_layout_put (GTK_LAYOUT (lytfsys), txtfsys, 32, 72);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (txtfsys, 128, 328);
  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (txtfsys)), _("\n\n\n    File system Area"), -1);

  return wndmain;
}


int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *wndmain;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  wndmain = create_wndmain ();
  gtk_widget_show (wndmain);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the philosophy of GTK3 is to steer more widget size/image/display functionality towards using CSS.  With that in mind, I took your program and added a CSS provider widget to your program.

```
GtkCssProvider *provider;
provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
```

I then deactivated the section that places your pixel image inside the window.

```
  //pixmap = gtk_image_new_from_file("pixmaps/layout-1920x1080.png");
  //gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (lytmain), pixmap);
  //gtk_widget_show (pixmap);
```

Then after the window widget had been defined, I defined the CSS style information for the provider and then associated the provider with the window widget.

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, "window.background {background-image: url(\"/home/craig/images/aaa 1335.jpg\") }", -1, NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider(gtk_widget_get_style_context(wndmain), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

Once the program was built, the various widgets appeared within the window.

[image: Sample Window]

So you might have to utilize CSS providers more in order to replicate the background behavior in GTK2.

Hope that helps.

Regards.